# insufficient_scope response from userinfo endpoint and missing scopes in jwt token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, spring-authorization-server

After I migrated the Spring Authorization Server from 0.3.1 to 1.0.0, I found that the userInfo endpoint returns `403`: `insufficient_scope`, after verifying the login process between the two versions I found that the endpoint `POST oauth2/token` is not returning the scope also the jwt token does not contain the scope, but the scope parameter in the URL is already mentioned while trying to login.

I am using the following configurations:

```
        registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(new ObjectId().toString())
                .clientId(oauthClient)
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder().encode(oauthClientSecret))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUris(uris -> uris.addAll(redirectUris))
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings
                        .builder()
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(8))
                        .build())
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings
                        .builder()
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                        .build())
                .build();
```

And this is the Http configurations:

```
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain = http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers(WELL_KNOWN_OPENID_CONFIGURATION).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/logout-success").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/health/status").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/assets/**", "/webjars/**", "/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(form -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll())
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .build();
```

I am using these URLs to test the login flow:

```
http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&code_challenge=<code_challenge>&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https://frontlocal:4600


http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&scope=openid&code=<code>&code_verifier=<code_verifer>&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://frontlocal:4600
```

**UPDATE**

```
2023-01-26T20:30:11.030+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter (20/23)
2023-01-26T20:30:11.031+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter (21/23)
2023-01-26T20:30:11.031+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter (22/23)
2023-01-26T20:30:11.031+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter (23/23)
2023-01-26T20:30:11.031+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OidcUserInfoAuthenticationProvider (1/13)
2023-01-26T20:30:13.819+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] a.o.a.OidcUserInfoAuthenticationProvider : Retrieved authorization with access token
2023-01-26T20:30:13.821+01:00 DEBUG 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
2023-01-26T20:30:13.822+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] s.s.o.s.a.o.w.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter : User info request failed: [insufficient_scope] 

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.authentication.OidcUserInfoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcUserInfoAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:559) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:52) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter.java:106) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter.java:147) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ...
    ...

2023-01-26T20:30:13.827+01:00 TRACE 150437 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
```

Comment: Have you [enabled openid connect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/5251eea3b8e811e1d1d5c78f40064288ea53eda8/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L66-L67)? It is no longer enabled by default in 1.0.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I tried what you provided in your response and it's not working and I also I think I already activated the OIDC by this code : `authorizationServerConfigurer.oidc(oidc -> oidc.userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userInfoMapper(userInfoMapper)));`

Comment: Can you provide your entire security configuration (if you have more than one filter chain, provide both configs)? I also wonder why you're setting `.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)` in your `RegisteredClient` since you have a client secret?

Comment: It may also be helpful to enable trace logging for all of spring security (including auth server) by `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` and provide the logs here.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg can you please see the trace logs in the updated question, as you can see, it bugs in the part while verifying the scopes in the token, and I already verified that there is no scopes saved in the DB. About this Method `.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)` , I added it because I am using the app for a SPA, it will not give me an access token if I remove it

Comment: Could you provide the trace logs for the entire flow? You only include a subset of one request (I assume the `/userinfo` request only). You say you're using `openid` scope but something appears to be amiss because the error you're receiving indicates that scope was not included in the issued access token. Also, as mentioned before it would be helpful for you to include your entire security config, including the `authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain` `@Bean`.

Answer (score 1):

Add **openid** scope in `spring-authorization-server/samples/messages-client/src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
          messaging-client-authorization-code:
            provider: spring
            client-id: messaging-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized"
            scope: openid, message.read,message.write
            client-name: messaging-client-authorization-code
```

Here is the sample http request/response:

```http
GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/userinfo
Authorization: Bearer <your token>

###

{
  "sub": "user1"
}
```

Works with version 1.0.0 of spring-authorization-server

Comment: I have added `openid` scope to the registered client. However, the JWT returned from `http://auth-server/oauth2/token` still doesn't contain this scope.

And auth server would error out if I request openid scope in the auth code URL like this:
`http://auth-server/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_url=yyy&scope=openid+read+write`